# Edit Reviews seem to be missing context

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Have a look at this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19019239) which was rejected. I edited the post after [someone else edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19018321) and removed the problem from the code in the question rendering all answers and tries for explanation useless.

The problem was, that the first edit removed an indention problem from the code, while the problem WAS the wrong indention. By editing the question instead of answering it, you cannot spot the problem of the asker anymore.

After I saw the problem (see the comments in the question), I reverted the [first edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19018321) in a way, that the problem in the question was making sense again.

Now there were two reviewers, which rejected my edit with the wrong reason `This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.` not getting the point of the edit.

I don't think its bad faith, but possibly (I cannot review edits myself, yet) the interface is not presenting enough context for the edit review so they could have seen why I edited the post.

Anyway, I think my edit should be approved, as the question is now still useless without the edit.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't think its bad faith, but possibly the interface is not presenting enough context for the edit review so they could have seen why I edited the post.

No, they just did a bad job.  The information that they were shown, and didn't properly consider, was your revision note, explaining that you were introducing a problem in the question *because you were referring an earlier edit that incorrectly removed the question's underlying problem*.  That's information that is essential for you to include in a revision note when making an edit of this nature, but because you *did* include it, the reviewers ought to have read it.  The fact that they didn't means that the error is on them.

I've gone back and reversed the improper change.